# What are the benefits of using html documents and nodes vs simple string manipulation in web scraping?

Tags: c#, html, string, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a webpage, so I can collect information from it.

To that end I saw a guide that shows how to make a web scraper using the library "Html Agility Pack". It is a library that provides classes for HTML node/element selection and data retrieval from them but after toiling on it I really don't see the point or benefit using high-level objects would give me over simple `string.substring`.

In both cases I have to get the HTML somehow and in both cases I have to know what the structure of the HTML is beforehand. But while I can just say `string.substring` from the element that interests me to the value I want to extract with said library and, I bet, other high end objects I have to instantiate them, navigate though their various methods that would break and explode if I don't use them by their specification, that I must also learn, toil over trying to make it all work with high end abstractions and best practices to end up with 100s of lines of code that will, I suppose, give me the exact same result as a 10 line `string.replace` code.

So is there any point in using high end objects for HTML data extraction over simple `string` methods?

Comment: which programming are you using....

Comment: @ShantanuSharma, C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using **HtmlAgilityPack** you can take desired html element and process it using library methods:

```
var htmlTable = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");
if (htmlTable == null)
   return null;


foreach (HtmlNode table in htmlTable)
{
     var rows = table.SelectNodes("tr");
     foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
     {
         // Here you can use very convenient methods of HtmlNode       
     } 
}
```

So you will have all convenient methods to handle HTML elements. In addition, with this library you can use methods which belongs to `string` type.

Otherwise, if you use `string` methods, then you have to take desired string using some methods such as:

- string.IndexOf()
- string.Substring()
- string.LastIndexOf()

instead of this simple code:

```
var htmlTable = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");
```